# Ajax X and Y position update not working correctly with Jquery UI draggables

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, jquery-ui

Could do with some help I have a simple ajax powered stickies app (with jquery UI and PHP) in development, my code below stores X, Y for dragged items posts it to a database and loops results back to a div. I have successfully built code for a text version (akin to post it notes) but I am trying to do a draggable/scalable version to hold images. But when I do this my positions are being stored in the database looped out into a #projbaord div but not being used to correctly position the HTML elements (i have checked the page source and the style: is showing correct x, y but this is not reflected on screen).

I think the problem must be in the loop out of the PHP and style of the position x, y but cannot seem to fathom it out! Any ideas or another way of achieving same result?

I thought this maybe a position:relative/absolute problem but that seems to be okay - I am stumped at present! Hope you can genius can help!

Javascript to handle behaviour and store values in database:

```
function imageStickyDragXYUpdate(){

    $(".imagesticky").each(function(index){

    var resizethese = $(this).children();

    $(this).draggable({
    cursor: 'move',
    stack: '.imagesticky',
    opacity: '0.5',
    containment: '#projboard',
    scrollspeed: '40',
    scrollSensitivity: '10',
    stop:function(){
        var coord=$(this).position();
        var coordLeft = coord.left;
        var coordTop = coord.top;
        var imageStickyid = $(this).attr('imagestickyid');
        //alert('x='+ coordTop + 'y=' + coordLeft + 'id=' +imageStickyid);

        var datastring = 'xupdateimg='+ coordTop + '&y=' + coordLeft + '&imgstickyid=' +imageStickyid + '&projid=' + proj_id + '&uid=' + uid;
        //alert(datastring);

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "uploaddata.php",
                data: datastring,
                success: function(data){
                            $("#projboardresults").html(data);
                            textStickyDragXYUpdate();//not important other function for working text stickies
                            imageStickyDragXYUpdate();

                            }
                });
    }
    });


           });


}
```

PHP to show results

```
<?php

$user_id= $_POST['uid'];
$proj_id=$_POST['projid'];//to be validated as int



$get_imgsticky_query = "SELECT * FROM imagesticky WHERE user_id = $user_id AND project_id=$proj_id";

                                $get_imgsticky_result=mysql_query($get_imgsticky_query);
                                while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get_imgsticky_result)){
                                $x = $row['imagesticky_x'];
                                $y = $row['imagesticky_y'];
                                $imagesticky_w = $row['imagesticky_w'];
                                $imagesticky_h = $row['imagesticky_h'];
                                $imagesticky_url = $row['imagesticky_url'];
                                $imagesticky_id = $row['imagesticky_id'];

                                echo '<div class="imagesticky" imagestickyid="'.$imagesticky_id.'" style="position: absolute; left:'.$x.'px; top:'.$y.'px;">
                                <a class = "clickaddimage" href="addimage.php"><img src="images/clicktoadd.png" alt="add image" title="Click to add image"</a>
                                <img src="'.$imagesticky_url.'" width="'.$imagesticky_w.'" height="'.$imagesticky_h.'"/>
                                <a href="" class="deleteimagesticky"><img src="images/closey.png" title="delete" alt="delete"/></a>
                                </div>';

                        }


?>
```

Comment: Seems like it should work correctly. Try to apply position: relative; to element that will contain stickies.

Comment: thanks for reply tryed relative and no change, very frustrating! LOL

Comment: Unfortunately without direct access to the page would be impossible to tell where's a problem. Take a 30 min break, drink a cup of tea and try to find problem again.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var datastring = 'xupdateimg='+ coordTop + '&y=' + coordLeft + '&imgstickyid=' +imageStickyid + '&projid=' + proj_id + '&uid=' + uid;
```

This line was the problem, I had the X variable storing the Y value and the Y coordinate storing the X variable! So my code appeared to be placing items in the wrong place, but was actually working perfectly. That is what you get for being a new father and trying to code! Why did I could not spot this yesterday? LOL!

Comment: lesson learned always take a break when trying to find an error!